# Probability drawing 20 from 80.

Tags: probability

Twenty numbers are drawn one at a time, without replacement, from a barrel containing numbers one to eighty.
Is it correct to say that the probability of a number being drawn in sequence i.e. 5 is drawn fifth etc, is 1/80.
If so is the distribution of such occurrences Binomial ?

Comment: Please rephrase "a number being drawn in sequence i.e. 5 is drawn fifth etc". In addition, try to clarify exactly what you're asking. For example - are you asking about the probability that **at least one number** is drawn "at the right position" of the sequence? Or are you asking about the probability that **all numbers** are drawn "at the right position" of the sequence? Or perhaps you mean **exactly one number**?

Comment: Is the probability of any one number being drawn in the right position 1/80 ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the probability that $5$ will be drawn at the $5$-th draw in this situation? Well, there are $80$ candidates and all of them have the same probability of being drawn at the $5$-th draw. So yes, the probability that $5$ is drawn at the $5$-th draw is indeed $\frac1{80}$.

If for $i=1,\dots,20$ we denote the result of the $i$-th draw by $D_i$ and define:  $$X=\#\{i\in\{1,\dots,20\}\mid D_i=i\}$$ then we can write: $$X=X_1+\cdots+X_{20}$$ where $X_i=1$ if $D_i=i$ and $X_i=0$ otherwise. A sum of iid Bernouilli random variables. However the $X_i$ are not independent so the conclusion that $X$ is binomially distributed is not valid.

To illustrate: draw all $80$ numbers instead of $20$ and realize that it is not possible that in this case $X$ takes the value $79$.

Comment: How would you calculate the probability of at least one number in the right position. Is this to do with derangements ?

Comment: I suspect you need inclusion/exclusion for that.